# if condition in a function - Makefile

Tags: makefile

I'm working with makefile and the very simple things like if-conditions are not straight forward. it gives me an error that is not readable.
Any idea what's wrong with my following small function?

```
prepare-test-example:
    ifeq ($(ENGINE),'aurora-postgresql')
        @cat examples/example.yaml > /tmp/stack_test.yaml
    else
        @cat examples/example.yaml examples/example_test.yaml > /tmp/stack_test.yaml
    endif
```

The call:

```
make test ENGINE=aurora-postgresql
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make prepare-test-example ENGINE=aurora-postgresql
ifeq (aurora-postgresql,'aurora-postgresql')
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `aurora-postgresql,'aurora-postgresql''
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `ifeq (aurora-postgresql,'aurora-postgresql')'
make[1]: *** [prepare-test-example] Error 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have indented the `ifeq` so it looks to `make` like something it should pass to the shell.

Try either

```
ifeq ($(ENGINE),'aurora-postgresql')
     files := examples/example.yaml
else
     files := examples/example.yaml examples/example_test.yaml
endif

prepare-test-example:
    @cat $(files)  > /tmp/stack_test.yaml
```

or

```
prepare-test-example:
    @if [ "$(ENGINE)" = "'aurora-postgresql'" ]; then \
        cat examples/example.yaml \
    ; else \
        cat examples/example.yaml examples/example_test.yaml \
    ; fi > /tmp/stack_test.yaml
```

For fun, I refactored out the redirection in the latter (pure shell script) example.

Perhaps you meant `ifeq('$(ENGINE)','aurora-postgresql')` which would make more sense, and allow for the above code to be simplified somewhat.

Comment: You should probably take out the `@` entirely, but I left it in to show where it needs to go.

Comment: note: first and second snippet do not have the same meaning and I suspect quotes in the first one are accidental (otherwise `ENGINE` would need to be literally `'aurora-postgresql'`).

Comment: @OndrejK. Huh? The one scenario where they won't be equivalent is if `ENGINE` contains a single quote.

Comment: Assuming `ENGINE` is set only once and not then changed, of course. If `ENGINE` is dynamically manipulated during the course of the Makefile, that complicates matters.

Comment: `ifeq ($(ENGINE),'aurora-postgresql')` seems to evaluate to true if `ENGINE="'aurora-postgresql'"`, the latter shell bound evalution if `ENGINE="aurora-postgresql"` (both examples are syntax passing it from cmdline, but you get the gist I think).